# Winforms UI stops showing values after some time in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, mqtt

I have code as below

```
if (textbox != null && topicindex == 0)
                {
                    textbox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    textbox.Text = Functions.Values(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.ApplicationMessage.Payload))));
                }
```

'Functions' is a static class and Values() is a method in it. If the conditions in the IF statement are met then Values method is called. These conditions come from an MQTT server. However, the UI stops after some time. My guess is that the Values method is called again during the time it is still being executed.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Stops = freezes, so you can't interact? Or just stop updating the values? How expensive is `Functions.Values`? Perhaps you should run it before invoke, store result in local variable and then do a quick invoke to just set text from captured variable.

Comment: UI still works. But values stop updating.

Comment: Then it could be because of something you didn't show. Pleaser refer to [mcve].